# Cannot open JSON file used both load and loads command in python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have tried both load and loads command but I am still getting the same error while loading my JSON file

```
import json
with open(photos.json) as f:
    data = json.load(f)
```

Then I am getting error

> ValueError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 - line 206950 column 1 (char 114 - 26888701)

when I use this code

```
import json
with open(photos.json) as f:
    data = json.loads(f)
```

I am getting error

> TypeError: expected string or buffer

I am unable to solve these errors please help.
thanks

here is the sample of my json file

> {"caption": "", "photo_id": "soK1szeyan202jnsGhUDmA", "business_id": "OnAzbTDn79W6CFZIriqLrA", "label": "inside"}
>   {"caption": "", "photo_id": "dU7AyRB_fHOZkflodEyN5A", "business_id": "OnAzbTDn79W6CFZIriqLrA", "label": "inside"}
>   {"caption": "", "photo_id": "6T1qlbBdKkXA1cDNqMjg2g", "business_id": "OnAzbTDn79W6CFZIriqLrA", "label": "outside"}
>   {"caption": "Bakery area", "photo_id": "lHhMNhCA7rAZmi-MMfF3ZA", "business_id": "OnAzbTDn79W6CFZIriqLrA", "label": "inside"}
>   {"caption": "", "photo_id": "oHSCeyoK9oLIGaCZq-wRJw", "business_id": "XaeCGHZzsMwvFcHYq3q9sA", "label": "food"}
>   {"caption": "", "photo_id": "EN9qzZpxfv00B_4X6q5lYA", "business_id": "XaeCGHZzsMwvFcHYq3q9sA", "label": "food"}
>   {"caption": "", "photo_id": "M6c0qxQQwWkUzAxIvoTFuQ", "business_id": "XaeCGHZzsMwvFcHYq3q9sA", "label": "food"}
>   {"caption": "", "photo_id": "876EKnk6deA7xA4i1aipJg", "business_id": "XaeCGHZzsMwvFcHYq3q9sA", "label": "food"}
>   {"caption": "", "photo_id": "NFCDwGr_-TEiw9bzx3nFKw", "business_id": "XaeCGHZzsMwvFcHYq3q9sA", "label": "food"}

Comment: `.loads(f)` is never going to work, that's load **s**tring. What's the content of the file - do you have more than one JSON object in there?

Comment: Your files is not valid JSON. It looks like JSON Lines, one JSON object per line. You have to iterate through the lines and parse them separately. If the objects are not separated by lines it's going to be harder.

Comment: How will I iterate through each line? How will I do that? Is there a code that can convert  this file to csv file?

Comment: Thanks alot I solved it I iterate it line by line and saved it in a list. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is not a such good idea for this problem, but we can replace '} {' with '}---{' and the split with this chars, and after that we create a list with all mini objects that you need. Try it maybe it will be fine for you, if not sorry.

```
import ast                                                                                                                                                                        

with open('./j.json') as f:
    data = f.readline().replace("} {", "}---{").split('---')

for value in [ast.literal_eval(x) for x in data]:
    print(value['photo_id'])
```

Comment: Thanks for your help